# How to bring Google Maps polygons within a certain coordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

I am using Google Maps Javascript library.
I have a database with polygons stored AND I would like to bring only the ones that fit in certain given coordinates.

Lets say I am standing at Lat 99.42333, Long -99.169333... how can I bring the polygons that are 1km around me? This is a huge table of polygons, so testing each is imposible.

I was thinking of adding 2 more columns "quadrant_lat" and "quadrant_lng" and then wrapping all the rows matching to it but I guess this is not the right way.

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient solution is to create geo indexes for the polygons in the database.  Almost all of the modern databases come with geo-indexing and querying capabilities pre-bundled or provide a plugin/library to do this.

The Geo indexes can be used to search for polygons within X meters radius for a given lat-long pair. This is the simplest of all geo searches, however, you can do a lot more advanced processing with 2D/3D geo indexes. On the map view/client, use google maps APIs to render the polygons returned by the geo query.

If your database does not have Geo capabilities, then you need to write code to do the heavy lifting yourself. The solution will depend on the size of your dataset.

What database are you using and how many polygons are there.?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am using MySQL and the polygons could be 100k+.

Comment: Ok. MySQL server has strong support for geo functions

Comment: For 100K+ records, you would definitely want to use indexes to query records. This means you don't need to be concerned about database scalability in the future even if the dataset grew further. MySQL server has strong support for geo functions. This blog post summarises the features with examples to show both index based searches as well as direct queries on the points stored in tables. https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-mysql-spatial-functions-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/